# The name "XXX" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MySpace" Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am converting my existing WP8 app to WP7.1. I placed several converter classes in the App.xaml Application.Resources section but Visual Studio complains that they do not exist in the namespace which they are.

All the converters are located inside the `Class Converter` folder.

The code works fine in WP8 project though so what do I need to change to make it compile in WP7.1?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:** I can now compile it. For some reason, one of the WP8 classes, (the multiresolution chooser) is preventing the project from compiling. I removed it since WP7 only support one resolution and that fixed it.

Comment: Can you compile and run the app? Maybe this is just an error in VS... You can try to write out the full name including the assembly e.g. `xmlns:mine="clr-namespace:Find_The_Cat;assembly=YourPorject.Name"`

Comment: I cannot compile and run the app in WP7.1

Comment: UPDATE: I can now compile it. For some reason, one of the WP8 classes, (the multiresolution chooser) is preventing the project from compiling. I removed it since WP7 only support one resolution and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that too :
You need to active 'show hidden folder' because AppData is hidden...

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Go to the folder location : "MY_USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\".
3. Delete the contents of the folders: 10.0 and 11.0.

[Here the link I found](http://codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2013/10/windows-phone-name-localizedstrings.html)