# XAML doesn't see my IValueConverter class

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a simple WP8, but I'm having troubles hiding (changing the *Visibility* property) on a control.

In XAML I've added `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectName"` (I've also tried with `using`).
The XAML is then structured as follows:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="MyProjectName.Pages.Main"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectName"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Margin="0,4,0,-4" Background="#FFBD3F3F">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" >
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:VisibilityFormatter x:Key="FormatConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="4">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Obj}" 
                                     Visibility="{Binding ObjVisibility, 
                                     Mode=OneWay, 
                                     Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The problem is at the `<local:...>` line: `The name "VisibilityFormatter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProjectName".`

The class is defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyProjectName
{
    public class Formatter
    {
        public class VisibilityFormatter : IValueConverter
        {
            // Retrieve the format string and use it to format the value.
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var visibility = parameter as bool?;
                return visibility.HasValue && visibility.Value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class `ObjInfo` is a simple public class with two properties:

```
namespace MyProjectName.Models
{
    public class ObjInfo
    {
        public bool ObjVisibility { get; set; }
        public string Obj { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267548/the-name-xxx-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespacemyspace-windows-p) question, but no migrating is involved. I'm developing on WP8 from the get-go.

**What am I trying to achieve?** Well. I'm storing whether the control should be visible or not in that `bool` property. Since the XAML control's property only grokks the `Visibility` `enum`, but not `bool`, I need to convert it to that `enum`.

Comment: Please post the full literal line defining the xmlns.

Comment: Did you compile the project? Sometimes the XAML designer doesn't pick up what classes exist until the project is built.

Comment: HenkHolterman I've updated the question. @Patrick: I've cleaned the whole solution and built it again, with the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `VisibilityFormatter` is an inner class of the `Formatter` class. You don't really need the `Formatter` class, just make the `VisibilityFormatter` a top class, and the XAML parser will find it.

Also, the general naming convention for converters is `XXXConverter` and not `XXXFormatter`, but that's no rule.

Comment: Ugh. I must be completely blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `MyProjectName.VisibilityFormatter` in your project, you have

```
MyProjectName.Formatter.VisibilityFormatter
```

You should remove `Formatter` class and leave only:

```
namespace MyProjectName
{
        public class VisibilityFormatter : IValueConverter
        {
            // Retrieve the format string and use it to format the value.
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var visibility = parameter as bool?;
                return visibility.HasValue && visibility.Value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    }
```

Comment: I get the same exact error still. Furthermore, VS throws an extra error saying that `MyProjectName.Formatter` namespace doesn't exist.